# Remove lines from text file without generating the files again

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing a Java program which stores user log when they are using the program.

To avoid making the `log.log` file (maybe replace as a variable later to save different log in different files) size too large, I would like to check if the file sizes is greater than, for example, 1024 bytes (i.e. 1kb), the oldest data (the first [few] lines) will be deleted before adding new log history as to ensure that the file size will not greater then 1kb before adding new logs. (Or it can be done after adding the log history and ensure the file size must smaller then 1kb.)

It means that if deleting 1 rows can let the files size smaller then 1kb, then just delete the first row. If it not enough, then delete first two row, etc.

```java
public void getLogHistory(String logContent) {
    File logFiles = new File("log.log"); // This is just a test, I may check to a variable and save to different log files under different situation
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String logStatement = "[" + timestamp.toString() + "] | " + logContent;

    try {
        logStatement += "\n";
        Files.write(Paths.get("log.log"), logStatement.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        
    }
}
```

I had checked different methods through Stack Overflow, or from the internet. However, all of those are teaching the method those creating a temp file to store and update all data required, then replace the temp file to the original file.

Through this method, I cannot count the rows from the temp files, therefore, I don't want to create a temp file for deleting rows.

Is/are there any method to do so? Or are there any improvements to make in my original code?

**I would like to add my own comments in my own log files, therefore, I would like to make my own log statement by modifying the a txt file, just don't border what I am doing for, I would just like to know how to check the files size of a file and if the file is larger then the limit, I can remove the first rows of the txt file, instead of creating a temp file and replace the files as to became a new file**

Comment: There are many logging frameworks out there that already handle various things that you must think about: appending to a log file, rolling over by size or by date, correctly handling multi-threading, and so on. Why bother with writing your own?

Comment: Slf4j  logback  refer to this page [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/)

Comment: 1kb will not give you that many log lines. Some individual lines may even be larger than 1kb. Also, default cluster sizes are typically at least 4kb, meaning that even a file that is 1 byte in size will take up 4kb reserved space on your disk. Therefore it's not worth doing what you suggest.

Comment: @k314159 – he said "for example, 1024 bytes" and "i.e. 1 kB". Usually this means that this can be adjusted to more feasible values once the basic concept works.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting off all the talking about logging (that can be of course solved much better by using a logging framework or JDK Logging), your problem is to remove some bytes from the beginning of a file before you add some new bytes to the end of it.

"Some bytes" means that there is no notion of lines; if you stuck with lines, you have to search from the beginning of the file to the first EOL marker to get the number of bytes to remove; in fact, that is the starting position for the bytes to keep, and that you now move to position 0.

The class that allows this is [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Moving bytes could be done like this (but this is the least efficient solution!):

```
public final void stripFirstBytes( final RandomAccessFile file, final long lengthToStrip )
{
  var writePos = 0L;
  var readPos = lengthToStrip;
  file.seek( readPos++ );
  final var value = file.read();
 
  while( value != EOF )
  {
    file.seek( writePos++ );
    file.write( value );
    file.seek( readPos++ );
    value = file.read();
  }
  file.setLength( file.getFilePointer() - lengthToStrip );
}
```

Of course you have to add the mandatory error handling (what happens, if the file is shorter than `lengthToStrip`?)! And, as said, this approach is very slow.

Comment: while, I would not like to create a temp a file, to replace of it. What I thinking of is creating a method, countBytes.
like using loop to check if I had line 1 size, if fileSize - line1 <maxSize, then it will return 1, if not, it will test if fileSize - line1 - line2 < maxSize, etc.... then it will check the number of lines required to get smaller then the maxSizes.

Comment: @Alex – think about what you wrote, then try to implement it. May be you have issues with the implementation because that does not work. So you should go for another approach. Hint: files does not contain lines, not even text; they consist of bytes, only of bytes. Anything else is an interpretation on reading them.